# Material Design for Angular 2 Typescript syntax error

Tags: css, typescript, angular-material

I'm learning Angular2 and modifying the ToDo app that I've scaffolded. The instructions for implementing Angular 2 Material Design read you should import the directives and providers then reference the styles in your page and then it reads:

...Or (more preferably) import them into your SCSS files.

```
$md-font-url: "node_modules/ng2-material/dist/";
@import "node_modules/ng2-material/dist/font";
@import "node_modules/ng2-material/source/all";
```

I put the code at the top of my CSS file but $md-font-url reports the Typescript syntax error "at-rule or selector expected". The code runs after the change but my heading is only one-half visible. I now have two style tags in the HTML header and the second one starts with "$md-font-url[_ngcontent-qtx-1]: "node_modules/ng2-material/dist/"[_ngcontent-qtx-1];"

What does the $ prefix represent and what is the purpose of the first line that I placed in the CSS? What at-rule or selector is it expecting?

Comment: The code is written in SCSS rather than pure CSS. And the error message is simply saying that if it isn't a valid CSS selector, then it could only be an @ rule; since it's neither, you get the error.

Comment: Can you tell me what the $ prefix represents and what is the purpose of the first line?

Comment: Words starting with a `$` are variables in SCSS. Se the [reference](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variables_).

Comment: Thank you for the answers and the reference link. I couldn't seem to enter correct search terms to find it.